# Python get float as array of floats from elasticsearch

Tags: python, arrays, elasticsearch

In elasticsearch one of my field stores an array of float values.  For example,

`-0.13672447204589844, 0.18057402968406677, -0.0991324931383133,`

I am trying to retrieve these values and store it in a float array.  I am using the following code:

```
res=es.search(index="g6jy834005er",body=data)
arr=[]
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    r="%(encod)s" % hit["_source"]
    print(r)
```

This prints the array like this:

```
[[-0.11659730970859528, 0.019643619656562805, 0.08672580868005753]]
[[-0.11659730970859528, 0.019643619656562805, 0.08672580868005753]]
[[-0.11659730970859528, 0.019643619656562805, 0.08672580868005753]]
[[-0.11659730970859528, 0.019643619656562805, 0.08672580868005753]]
```

When I check for type of array, using `print(type(r))` I am getting

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

I tried the following to convert the str array to float:

```
Trial 1
res = [ eval(x[0]) for x in r ]

Trial 2
res = np.asarray(r, dtype=np.float64, order='C')

Trial 3
res = list(map(float,r))
```

None of them worked.  How can I convert the str array to float array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
res=es.search(index="g6jy834005er",body=data)
arr=[]
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    r="%(encod)s" % hit["_source"]
    r=ast.literal_eval(r)
    print(r)
```

The type now would be as expected, a `list`, but if you want a numpy array:

```
import ast
res=es.search(index="g6jy834005er",body=data)
arr=[]
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    r="%(encod)s" % hit["_source"]
    r=np.array(ast.literal_eval(r))
    print(r)
```

Then the type would be a numpy array.

Comment: @u9forward Thank you for the super quick answer...both the options helped me.   I have not come across the ast library so far.  Thank you.  Will accept your answer in 7 mins